# Why debian library packages have numbers in their name?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I was installing some dependency libraries using `apt` and I was just wondering why some debian library packages have number in their names.

For example:

- `libleveldb1` (while development package is `libleveldb-dev` and debug package is `libleveldb-dbg`)
- `librados2` (while there is no `librados1`, the development package is `librados-dev` and the debug package is `librados2-dbg`)

They don't seem to be version numbers because there is no version 2 for `librados`. I just don't understand what are all these numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, package version is more or less related to the underlying library version AND/OR library ABI. So some careful releaser will prefix their package with the major version number of the library, so as one day, somebody can install `libleveldb1` and `libleveldb2` alongside on the same server (and have program that use any of the two version without issue).

`-dev` and `-dbg` packages are also usually used by developers who know what they do, so removing the extra version name at the end of the package is ok. At least, until there is a version 2 of `liblevel` which will then call for a `libleveldb1-dbg` and `libleveldb1-dev` packages.

The librados has existed in version 1 and version 2 is now the usual version, see the changelog at http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/c/ceph/ceph_0.72.2-2_changelog for more information:

`Rename librados1{,-dbg,-dev} packages to librados2{,-dbg,-dev} ones;
    conflict with and replace the former ones.`

So as a conclusion, these versions are convenience numbers that usually follow the underlying library version number, but now always.

Comment: Actually, these numbers should never map to the actual version of the library. If they do, it's (sadly) often the case the library developer had no clue what to do here. A good explanation can be found in the Autotools Mythbuster: https://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/libtool/version.html

Comment: I think @zhenech is right. librados have never had a version 2 or even 1! It seems that this number is just a debian specific revision number.

Comment: @Ali it's not *Debian* specific, it's the SONAME/ABI-version of the library, which Debian includes in the package name.